# Azure Active directory (ADAL) doesn't redirect you to the page you are trying to open when you have to login

Tags: angularjs, azure, adal, adal.js

I'm working on an application using Framework 4.6.2 and angularjs, We are using adal.js and adal-angular.js. The problem we are experiencing is that when you are logout of the application and click on a hyperlink that point to the aplication (not the root of the app) after login on xxxx.onmicrosoft.com it redirect you to the root.

For example you click on a link or put the following url in the browser

http://localhost:4434/#/ticket/search

The application takes you to the login page:

[image]

After that it redirect me to the root

http://localhost:4434/#/

instead of http://localhost:4434/#/ticket/search

Here is the code I have in place:

```
      adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init({
            tenant: 'xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com',
            clientId: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx',
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            popUp: true
        }, $httpProvider);
```

.when("/tickets/search", {
                    controller: "TicketsSearchController",
                    templateUrl: "app/tickets/templates/search.html",
                    allowNavBack: true,
                    requireADLogin: true
                })
we are using AdalJS and ADAL-angular v1.0.14

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.13.9

This is how the Startup class looks like

```
 public class Startup
     {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
         {

       app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
               new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                Tenant = "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                 ValidAudience = "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/"
                }

            });
        app.UseAeActiveDirectoryViaAzureAuthentication(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"],
            WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"]);

        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

The issue is that no matter what url you are trying to go, it always redirects you to the url I specified on Azure which is the same I use in web.config

But the expected result is that if you navigate to a url like http://localhost:4434/#/ticket/search after you login you should be redirected to that Url not to the root http://localhost:4434

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Jose

Answer (score 2):

This root cause is that the ADAL check the state whether is protected by Azure AD before the location is changed. So the ADAL will save the current location as `loginStartPage`. To make sure the page redirect to the path previews visiting, we can change the source code of ADAL.

For example, we can change the [stateChangeHandler function](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal-angular.js#L257) to log the path and then modify the [loginHandler](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal-angular.js#L182) to change the login page as we wanted.

```
var stateChangeHandler = function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    if (toState) {
                        var states = getStates(toState);
                        var state = null;
                        for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
                            state = states[i];
                            if (isADLoginRequired(state, _adal.config)) {
                                if (!_oauthData.isAuthenticated) {
                                    if (!_adal._renewActive && !_adal.loginInProgress()) {
                                        _adal.info('State change event for:' + $location.$$url);
                                        //pass the url here
                                        loginHandler(toState.url);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
 ...

var loginHandler = function (path) {
    _adal.info('Login event for:' + $location.$$url);
    if (_adal.config && _adal.config.localLoginUrl) {
        $location.path(_adal.config.localLoginUrl);
    }
    else {
        // directly start login flow
        _adal.info('Start login at:' + $location.$$absUrl);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('adal:loginRedirect');
        //change the loginStatePage here
        _adal.login($location.$$absUrl+'#!'+path);
    }
};
```

This is a workaround for this issue, to support redirecting the specific route after ADAL authentication using the raw ADAL for JavaScript, I suggest that you reopen a new issue from [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues).